# How to install nodejs in CentOS

Tags: node.js, centos

I am getting an issue... when I try to install nodejs in Centos I use this command:

```
yum install nodejs
```

But this command install the version 6... I mean when I use the command

```
node -v
```

It says 6

BUT I need to install the version 12 not the version 6, then I try to update it but when I update it... It install the version 12 in the folder

```
bin/local/n/versions/12.3.0
```

And If I use the command node -v it still says version 6... so I wonder..

How can I install the node version 12 in CentOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can compile and install from source, first install the pre-requisites:

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ make
```

Then download the source files and extract:

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.3.0/node-v12.3.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf node-v12.3.0.tar.gz
cd node-v12.3.0
```

If you need the latest version, use this url: https://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz

Then configure and install:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then check the version installed by running:

```
node --version
```

if you get python errors, you need to install other dependencies and use python for configuration:

```
yum install python27 openssl-devel
```

and use this commands instead:

```
python2.7 configure
make PYTHON=python2.7
make install
```